# How to save a dictionary Python Edit: Can use pickle

Tags: python, dictionary, passwords

for a small project I was just messing around with dictionaries to make a password system. I am new to this so bear with me:

```
users = {"user1" : "1234", "user2" : "1456"}

print ("Welcome to this password system")
print ("Please input your username")

choice = input ("")

print ("Please enter your password")

choice2 = input ("")

if (choice in users) and (choice2 == users[choice]):
    print ("Access Granted")
else:
    print ("Access Denied. Should I create a new account now?")
    newaccount = input ("")
    if newaccount == "yes" or "Yes":
        print ("Creating new account...")
        print ("What should your username be?")
        newuser = input ("")
        print ("What should your password be?")
        newpass = input ("")
        users.update({newuser:newpass})
```

I am using the update to add it to a dictionary, but when I exit the program, the new updates do not register?

How could I go about in the most simple way possible to add and save people's accounts to a dictionary?

Thanks,
A new programmer.

Comment: Maybe you should elaborate a little as _"How could I go about in the **most simple** way possible to add and save people's accounts to a dictionary?"_ and _"not using Pickle"_ are rather conflicting requirements.

Comment: maybe JSON https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html

Comment: Heh, sorry about that, I am new to this. Due to it being at school, they wont allow the addition of pickle to the python as it all has to be done with the basic python IDLE commands. If that means it's complicated, then so be it. I'm over complicating this for a lesson anyway.

Comment: @Bob no problem. I just wanted to point out the fact that Pickle, just like the JSON encoder have _very_ simple interface. Basically `dump(dictionary, file)`. See https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html#pickle.dump and https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html#pickle.dump . Both are standard modules, so should be available from IDLE. That being said, if you are not _allowed_ to use any module, things are going much more complicated _and_ much less realistic...

Comment: Hang on, is pickle apart of the base Python IDLE system?

Comment: Edit: I can now use pickle for the program. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: @Bob: Can you check my answer is useful or not??

Comment: @vivek can't right now - at the dentist

Comment: ok, no problem. let me know ii any issue comes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `pickle`  module for that. 
This module have two methods,

1. **Pickling(dump)**: Convert Python objects into string representation.
2. **Unpickling(load)**: Retrieving original objects from stored string representstion.

https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/pickle.html
code:

```
>>> import pickle
>>> l = [1,2,3,4]
>>> with open("test.txt", "wb") as fp:   #Pickling
...   pickle.dump(l, fp)
... 
>>> with open("test.txt", "rb") as fp:   # Unpickling
...   b = pickle.load(fp)
... 
>>> b
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

for dictionary:

```
>>> import pickle
>>> d = {"root_level1":1, "root_level2":{"sub_level21":21, "sub_level22":22 }}
>>> with open("test.txt", "wb") as fp:
...     pickle.dump(d, fp)
... 
>>> with open("test.txt", "rb") as fp:
...     b = pickle.load(fp)
... 
>>> b
{'root_level2': {'sub_level21': 21, 'sub_level22': 22}, 'root_level1': 1}
```

---

related to your code:

1. Get values from the userdetails file by `pickle load()` method.
2. Used `raw_input` to get values from the user. (Use `input()` for `Python 3.x`)
3. Check Access is granted or not.
4. Create New user but check username is already exist in system or not.
5. Add new user details in the users dictionary.
6. Dump users details into file by `pickle dump()` method.

Set default values to file:

```
>>> import pickle
>>> file_path = "/home/vivek/workspace/vtestproject/study/userdetails.txt"
>>> users = {"user1" : "1234", "user2" : "1456"}
>>> with open(file_path, "wb") as fp:
...     pickle.dump(users, fp)
... 
>>>
```

Or Handle exception when file is not present
e.g.

```
try:
    with open(file_path,"rb") as fp:
        users = pickle.load(fp)
except FileNotFoundError:
    users = {}
```

code:

```
import pickle
import pprint

#- Get User details
file_path = "/home/vivek/workspace/vtestproject/study/userdetails.txt" 
with open(file_path, "rb") as fp:   # Unpickling
  users = pickle.load(fp)

print "Existing Users values:"
pprint.pprint(users)


print "Welcome to this password system"
choice = raw_input ("Please input your username:-")
choice2 = raw_input ("Please enter your password")

if choice in users and choice2==users[choice]:
    print "Access Granted"
else:
    newaccount = raw_input("Should I create a new account now?Yes/No:-")
    if newaccount.lower()== "yes":
        print "Creating new account..."
        while 1:
            newuser = raw_input("What should your username be?:")
            if newuser in users:
                print "Username already present."
                continue
            break

        newpass = raw_input("What should your password be?:")
        users[newuser] = newpass

    # Save new user
    with open(file_path, "wb") as fp:   # pickling
        pickle.dump(users, fp)
```

Output:

```
$ python test1.py
Existing Users values:
{'user1': '1234', 'user2': '1456'}
Welcome to this password system
Please input your username:-user1
Please enter your password1234
Access Granted

$ python test1.py
Existing Users values:
{'user1': '1234', 'user2': '1456'}
Welcome to this password system
Please input your username:-test
Please enter your passwordtest
Should I create a new account now?Yes/No:-yes
Creating new account...
What should your username be?:user1
Username already present.
What should your username be?:test
What should your password be?:test

$ python test1.py
Existing Users values:
{'test': 'test', 'user1': '1234', 'user2': '1456'}
Welcome to this password system
Please input your username:-
```

Answer (score 0):

When your program starts

```
import os
import json
FILEPATH="<path to your file>" 
try:
   with open(FILEPATH) as f: #open file for reading
       users = json.loads(f.read(-1)) #read everything from the file and decode it
except FileNotFoundError:  
   users = {}
```

and in the end

```
with open(FILEPATH, 'w') as f: #open file for writing
     f.write(json.dumps(users)) #dump the users dictionary into file
```

Comment: You shouldn't "check-before-open" as this is open to a race condition is the file is deleted between the two calls. You should open the file and be prepared to handle the possible `FileNotFound` exception.

Comment: @SylvainLeroux indeed. I'm amending it

Answer (score 0):

You have several options so save dictionary *easily* using only *standard* modules. In the comments, you where pointed to [JSON](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.dump) and [Pickle](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html#pickle.dump). Both have very similar interface for basic usage.

As you are studying Python, may I suggest you to take a look at the very good [Dive Into Python 3 ‣ Ch 13: Serializing Python Objects](http://www.diveintopython3.net/serializing.html). This will answer most of your questions (*and* your teacher's questions ?) regarding the use of one of these modules or the other.

---

As a complement, here is a very simple examples using Pickle:

```
import pickle
FILEPATH="out.pickle"

# try to load
try:
    with open(FILEPATH,"rb") as f:
        users = pickle.load(f)
except FileNotFoundError:
   users = {}

# do whantever you want
users['sylvain'] = 123
users['sonia'] = 456

# write
with open(FILEPATH, 'wb') as f:
     pickle.dump(users, f)
```

This will produce a *binary* file:

```
sh$ hexdump -C out.pickle
00000000  80 03 7d 71 00 28 58 07  00 00 00 73 79 6c 76 61  |..}q.(X....sylva|
00000010  69 6e 71 01 4b 7b 58 05  00 00 00 73 6f 6e 69 61  |inq.K{X....sonia|
00000020  71 02 4d c8 01 75 2e                              |q.M..u.|
00000027
```

---

And using JSON now:

```
import json
FILEPATH="out.json"

try:
    with open(FILEPATH,"rt") as f:
        users = json.load(f) 
except FileNotFoundError:
   users = {}

users['sylvain'] = 123
users['sonia'] = 456

with open(FILEPATH, 'wt') as f:
```

Basically the same code, replacing `pickle` by `json` *and* opening the file as *text*. Producing the *text* file:

```
sh$ $ cat out.json 
{"sylvain": 123, "sonia": 456}
#                             ^
#                         no end-of-line here
```